# R:rank of augmented matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Is there a way to get rank of augmented matrix. I want to test for dependence with this theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem

I tried a bit wiht qr() function, but with no luck.

Comment: might want to explain how you have the augmented matrix is in R.

Comment: Yes, this is also an issue...I don't know how to combine A and b in augmented matrix as well.(all terminology is expained in wiki link)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A <- matrix(1:4, 2)
A
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4   

b <- matrix(5:6, 2)
b
#      [,1]
# [1,]    5
# [2,]    6

qr(A)$rank
# [1] 2

aug <- cbind(A, b)
aug 
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    5
# [2,]    2    4    6

qr(aug)$rank
# [1] 2
```